# Is it possible to pass the system variable defined in XML as a function parameter in CAPL

Tags: xml, capl

I have some 20 messages defined as a structure and for each message I have many signals(not the exact signal name as of dbc) which I have defined as system variable in an XML file.

In CAPL if I search @sysvar ,I see both my signal name and namespace(message name) being displayed.

Now I need to create a function where in I need to change the value of a signal .For that I need to pass structure (namespace )name ,its signal name and value to be written as arguments .

I am unable to do this .

Can anyone help me in how to pass the namespace and signal name defined in XML as an argument in CAPL.

The format of XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<systemvariables version="4">
  <namespace name="" comment="" interface="">
    <namespace name="XYZ" comment="" interface="">
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="ABC" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="false" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="1" />

   </namespace> 
  </namespace>
</systemvariables>
```

I need to pass Name and namespace as an argument to function in CAPL?Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** *Do you need just simply set your sysVar?*

```
@<sys> = 12; //ex @XYZ::ABC = 1 OR @sysvar::<sys> = 12; //  @sysvar::XYZ::ABC
```

**Option 2** *Do you need function which takes sysvar?*

```
//Function Definition
void FunctionWithSysVariableAsParameter(sysvarInt *sys,int valueToAssign)
{
  @sys = valueToAssign; 
}


//Usage Example
on start
{
  FunctionWithSysVariableAsParameter(sysvar::XYZ::ABC,12);
  write("%d",@XYZ::ABC);
}
```

**Option 3** *Do you  need function which takes sysvar **names**?*

To achieve this you can use build-in function lookupSysvar.

```
//Function Definition
void FunctionWithSysVariableNameAsParameter(char sysVarNamespace[],char variableName[],int valueToAssign)
{
  sysvarInt * myLocalSysvar;
  myLocalSysvar = lookupSysvarInt(sysVarNamespace,variableName);
  @myLocalSysvar = valueToAssign;
}
//Usage Example
on start
{
  FunctionWithSysVariableNameAsParameter("XYZ","ABC",15);
  write("%d",@XYZ::ABC);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !! It worked ...Perfect solution and I used Option 3. I was not aware of "lookupSysvarInt" .Kudos to your knowledge .

Comment: @Akash, if the answer is useful and solved your problem, consider accepting it.